# batch loop through "filtered" files list

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I want to iterate over a list of files which end with .txt but not .old.txt.
That is file1.txt should be listed, but file4.old.txt should not.

I know this is used to iterate over files:

```
for /r .\logs %%G in (*.txt ) do (
    echo %%G
)
```

But when I try to add an if:

```
for /r .\logs %%G in (*.txt ) do (
    if x%%G:.old.txt=%==x%%G (
        echo %%G
    )
)
```

I get: `=G was unexpected at this time`

I tried to assign the value to a "normal" variable:

```
for /r .\logs %%G in (*.txt) do (
    set F=%%G

    if x%F:.old.txt=%==x%F% (
        echo %F%
    )
)
```

but to no avail, I just get one file printed a few times...

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.txt^|findstr /ive "\.old\.txt"') do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r .\logs %%G in (*.txt ) do (
    echo %%G|findstr /v /i /e /l ".old.txt"
    )
)
```

should filter out those filenames.

The real question is no doubt "why didn't the code I tried work as I'd expected?"

With the first attempt, it's not possible to substring a metavariable (eg. `%%G`)

With the second, you need to use `delayed expansion` in order to use a variable's changing value in a block. There are many, many examples of this phenomenon on SO - just look for `delayed expansion`.

The way the solution I propose works is to filter the value of `%%G` through `findstr` which is looking for strings that `/e` - end with, `/i` case-insensitively, `/v` NOT-matching `/l` literal-string provided.

Comment: Thanks!  your explanation of why my code does not work helped me to understand a few things..  your solution works well when it's only to `echo`, but when I need to concat the file name to a list of file names (`set SOURCE_FILES=!SOURCE_FILES! %%a`) it doesn't work..

Comment: `echo %%G|findstr /v /i /e /l ".old.txt" >nul || echo %%G` <--- It actually needs this to use the loop variable where the second echo %%G is the one to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r .\logs %%G in (*.txt) do (
    set F=%%G
    if "!F:.old.txt=!" == "!F!" (
        echo !F!
    )
)
```

Comment: With this I get the right number of files printed out, but all the prints are the same..  Even though I have `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: @NitzanTomer   use better `echo !F!`